# Changing data value in sql table on specific date?

Tags: php, python, sql

I am trying to build a serial code control system based on Mysql and php as api.

Taking a scenario that a serial has a been generated on 3:00 AM (as the serials will have 1 hour validity ) on 4:00 AM its data will altered in the status column from 1 to 0 (1 means haven't expired 0 means expired).

I have designed the api such that if the serial exist then check for the status if its 1 then true else false

Now, I can't manually change the data from 1 to 0. I want this to be automated

I thought of building another api to return time of each serial then use it in a python script which can run 24/7 and check if time is more than an hour or less based on that it will call another api which will alter the value

I want to know if their are any other ways of doing this rather than running a python script 24/7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look into cron jobs to execute the script and run the query every x minutes, say 5.

https://crontab.guru/